# Wrapping Text Using Modulo

Tags: c, text, cs50

I am trying to cipher some plain text using a string key.  Anyway if the plain text is greater than the key the key is suppose to continue using the key..I have used modulo to make the key start over again but for some reason it is not working...what is wrong with the code? By the way the key status upper or lower status is not a factor so this is why I change it to lower. Any help rendered would be appreciated. //Code cleaned up as suggested.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])

{


if (argc != 2)
{

  printf("Ouch missing key\n");

return 1;
}

//get encryption keyword from argv array
string k= (argv[1]); 

//test for non aplha character in plain text message

int x;

for (x = 0; x <strlen(argv[1]); x++)
        {

    if(isalpha(k[x]) == false)

        {
printf("Ouch ensure value is alphabetical only\n");

return 1;

        }
  }

string m;


m = GetString(); //get plain text from prompt


for (int i= 0, j = 0; i< strlen(m) && j<= strlen(k); i++, j++)


{

    if (

        isalpha(m[i]) && isupper(m[i]))

            {

                m[i]= (m[i]-'a' + (tolower(k[j % strlen(k)])-'a')) % 26 + 'A';

            } 

    else if (

        isalpha(m[i]) && islower(m[i])

        )
            { 

           m[i] = (m[i] - 'a' + (tolower(k[j %strlen(k)])- 'a')) % 26 + 'a';


            }

    else 
         m[i] = m[i];
}

printf("%s\n", m);

}
```

Comment: Is this `C` or `C++`? If its C, then how is `string` defined? If C++, is it std::string, or something else? And if it's std::string, how does strlen(m) even compile? And, what does `GetString` actually return?

Comment: I didn't get it. What exactly wrong? Decipher your message (That: `"if the plain text is greater than the key the key is suppose to continue using the key"`, and that: `"By the way the key status upper or lower status is not a factor so this is why I change it to lower"`). Also, it would be nice if you clean up your code (huge spaces and misleading comments). Hard to read it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[]){
    if (argc != 2){
        printf("Ouch missing key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    string k = argv[1];
    int len_k = strlen(k);

    for (int i = 0; i < len_k; ++i){
        if(isalpha(k[i]))
            k[i] = tolower(k[i]);
        else {
            printf("Ouch ensure value is alphabetical only\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    string m;
    m = GetString();

    for (int i= 0; i< m[i] ; ++i){
        if(isupper(m[i]))
            m[i]= (m[i]-'A' + k[i % len_k] - 'a') % 26 + 'A';
        else if(islower(m[i]))
            m[i]= (m[i]-'a' + k[i % len_k] - 'a') % 26 + 'a';
        else 
            m[i] = m[i];//no effect, no need
    }

    printf("%s\n", m);
    free(m);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your coding language is `C` fix `main()` by,

`int main (int argc, string argv[])`

to

`int main (int argc, char * argv[])`

Comment: The coding languiage is C.  GetString() gets what the user plain text at the prompt which is denoted by m [message].  Therefore strlen(m) takes the length of the plain text. Regaring the wrapping if for example the user types plain text "hello" at prompt and cipher k is abc, it takes h moves it by a, e by c, l by c and then it cipher the other l by a and o by b etc.  The correct output in this case is  hfnlp since a is 0, b is 1, c is 1 etc but mine returns hgllo.  I do agree about the code mess, I am moving things all over the place in a bid to resolve problem.

Comment: Regarding "int main (int argc, char * argv[])" I have stated as per the requirement of the course.

Comment: I have sorted it out. I had to check for the length of the key less than the length of the message.